# JQuery not loading CSS, js

Tags: jquery

I have couple of issues with my jsp.

1. Javascript and CSS dont get loaded using relative path

   ```
      <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/mywebapp.css"/>      
      <script src="../js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script> $(document).ready(function(){
   ajaxdGetStats();
   setInterval("ajaxdGetStats()",10000);
   }); </script>
   ```

Using the F12 I could figure out that the request for css and js goes to /css/bootstrap.min.css and /js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js whereas it should go to /mywebapp/css/bootstrap.min.css and /mywebapp/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js

2. The $(document).ready(function(){...}); throws an error below.

The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object

My web directory structure is as below -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKpfg.gif)

I am using Spring MVC and below is my web.xml servlet configuration

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven />       
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- resources exclusions from servlet mapping -->
<!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" /> -->
```

Comment: Try going two directories up `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.min.css"/>`.

Comment: Thanks @RedHat, but going two directories up didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the path is wrong. Probably in the following lines:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: have doubled checked the paths and the filenames. Everything is correct. Infact, I am able to load these files into the browser  with the http://<hostname>:<port>/myapp/js/bootstrap.min.js and http://<hostname>:<port>/myapp/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js

Comment: @bipin _property '$' is null or undefined_ appears when the file is not included or the content is incorrect. If I were you, I would check again. 

Just a tip: if you are usng chrome or firefox, you can check the included files content in the browser console (F12 > Resources in chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Carlos for your help. A couple of things worked,
1. The browser was caching the previous compiled jsps, I had to clear the cache and 'touch' the jsps to force the browser to refresh the cache. This way it picked up the new path.
2. For IE10, I had to include the  tag in the jsp. More info on the X-UA-Compatible tag is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e)